# Update a model value on Html.TextBoxFor() onchange event without submitting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, onchange

I have a textbox that I call in my view like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.ActivityIDReturn)
```

What I'd like to be able to do is whenever a value is inserted into this textbox I would like it to update the model without having to hit any type of submit button. Several elements are populated in the view by the value of this textbox.

So ideally the textbox would looks something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.ActivityIDReturn, new with {Key .onchange=UpdateModel()})
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.ActivityIDReturn, new with {Key .onchange= RETLog(ActivityIDReturn:=ActivityIDReturn)})
```

*RETLog() being the function that creates the view in the firstplace.*

So far the only way I've been able to accomplish this is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.ActivityIDReturn, New With {Key .onchange = "javascript:submit()"})
```

But I can only imagine what horrible side effects might come from this kind of thing.

**EDIT: Exactly what I am trying to accomplish here**

In My Model I have this:

```
Public Property PS As RecordsTaskView
            Get
                Return GlobalVar.db.PS.RecordsTaskViews.Find(ActivityIDReturn)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As RecordsTaskView)
                value = GlobalVar.db.PS.RecordsTaskViews.Find(ActivityIDReturn)
            End Set
End Property
```

In my view I have This:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.ActivityIDReturn)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.ActivityIDReturn, New With {Key .onchange="javascript:submit()"})
 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.RefActionID)
 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.QutDesc)
 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.TaskDesc)
 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.CltCode)
 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.CltDesc)
 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.PS.BenIDin)
```

Basically all of these DisplayFor are populated by the value of this textbox.  I would like these DisplayFor values to populate when the user enters a value in the textbox without the user having to refresh the page, or hitting enter or hitting any buttons.

Here is a view at my code in it's entirety: https://gist.github.com/aaronmallen/7042328

Comment: I think you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how MVC works and the separation between client and server.  Once a view has been rendered and sent to the client, it is essentially done with the server side model.

Comment: @jmoerdyk I understand how MVC works. Basically I am trying to get the form from the view to postback to the controller without actually submitting everything to the model.

Comment: do that using `Ajax.BeginForm()`....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use a jquery ajax call.

```
$('#ActivityIDReturn').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            Text: $('#TextField').val()
        },
        success: function (_result) {
            $('#TaskDesc').val(_result.foo);
        }
     });
});
```

I haven't done for's like you have in your fiddler.  I have always done them with lamda's  something like

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.TaskDesc)
```

which will auto generate an id of TaskDesc.  You will need to look at your generated Html to make sure that the id's you call in your jquery match.

and a controller method

```vb
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function UpdateFields(Text As String) As ActionResult
    Dim model as MODELNAME = //query the database
    Return Json(New With { .foo = model.bar, .baz = model.baz });
End Function
```

this will fire every time the field changes so if they type a word with 10 letters it will fire 10 times.  Hopefully this helps

Comment: So what do I put in the //update fields area?  @Model.ActivityIDReturn = TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.ActivityIDReturn)?

Comment: I don't know enough about what you are wanting to do,  With this code the value of your text box will be passed back to the controller where you can do something and pass a value/s back to the view (_result in the code).  so you could do something like $('#text1').val(_result.text1); to update a text field with values from the controller

Comment: Basically this textbox when given a value populates a whole bunch of HTML.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.RandomElementToDisplay) What I am trying to accomplish is these DisplayFor elements would populate automatically without the user having to submit or refresh when they enter a value into this textbox.

Comment: thats what this code will do.  put a class or an id on the displayfor elements and using jquery selectors you can set them with values returned from the controller.  $('#Display1').val(_return.Display1);  Something like that will set the fields.  with change it will fire every time the field changes.  you may want to look at blur(lost focus), keyup, keydown, etc

Comment: `change` only gets raised when an input field has been changed and looses focus. If the user types in a 10 letter word it will only execute the ajax when they click off the field. `keypress` will get raised with every key press, as the name implies.

Comment: @Jay thank you for the clarification. arronmallen please see my edit above

Comment: Sorry for the delay,  Looking at your code I didn't see a reference to jquery.  You will need to have a reference to jquery for the ajax post to work.  On most browsers if you hit f-12 it will open the console where you can see any error messages that you are encountering.  Can you add a reference and post any errors you get after that point?

Comment: @MattBodily I call my jQuery v1.10.2 in the Layout file included on that gist. EDIT: I'm an idiot lol, I call the jQuery after I call this script.  I'll adjust and retest on monday.

Comment: @MattBodily Still no dice.  I have updated https://gist.github.com/aaronmallen/7042328 to show you the code with the appropriate changes.

Comment: @MattBodily None, should I maybe use Ajax.BeginForm() instead of HTML.BeginForm() and if so what are the Ajax options(required)?

Comment: this ajax call sends the data so you don't need the ajax form tags for it.  So no errors but when you click on the button that fires the ajax call nothing happens?

Comment: @MattBodily tried adding a simple Alert command and sure enough it throws up an alert box, so I'm not 100% what the issue is here. `$('#ActivityIDReturn').change(function(){alert( "Handler for .change() called." );});`

Comment: that is good that the alert gets hit.  does the controller method ever get hit?

Comment: From what I can see in your code the controller should be hit.  I see in your controller you have the model as an input option.  With an ajax call the only way you can send the model to the controller is by building it.  Add the different parameters of the model to the data object of the ajax call and make sure the names match exactly and it will send.  For the return from the controller you have a . in front of the parameter name.  I haven't used vb in years so that may be part of the language but you don't need that in c#